# How do disable the Radio button in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is my problem .On change of the Data in the textfield txt1  we send a request to json file which outputs the status of that value entered in thetextfield with that status (Y means ) "Yes " is checked and (N means) "No"  is checked   and if no value is present 
than "NO" is only checked. Here is the code below  but for ex if we enter  "213 " value means "A" so  status is "YES"   so "YES" is checked  and "NO"  is "DISABLED" ."214 "  means  "B"  so status means "NO"  so "NO " is checked    and "disabled"  and  " yes" is also "disabled ".  The "NO " should only be checked and not"DISABLED" this 
might be we have "DISABLED" in the previous "YES".

```
$.getJSON("test.php",{'val' : $("#txt1").attr('value'),'cde' :$("#txt2").attr('value')},
                    function(data){                                         
                      if(data[0].status){                           
                            switch(data[0].status){
                            case 'A':  
                                $('#rb_Statusyes').attr('checked',true);
                                $('#rb_Statusno').attr('disabled','disabled');                              
                                break;
                            case 'B':           
                                $('#rb_Statusno').attr('checked',true);
                                $('#rb_Statusyes').attr('disabled','disabled');
                                break;
                            case '':            
                                $('#rb_Statusno').attr('checked',true);
                                $('#rb_Statusyes').attr('disabled','disabled');
                                break;          
                            }
                      }
```

Comment: alright, if you polish this question up just a bit, I might actually be able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your problem is that you've previously set the attribute and you now need to remove it.

```
$('#rb_Statusno').attr('checked',true);
$('#rb_Statusno').removeAttr('disabled'); // Also remove the previously added disabled
$('#rb_Statusyes').attr('disabled','disabled');
$('#rb_Statusyes').removeAttr('checked'); // Also remove the previously added checked
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks ok the code but try this

```
//disable  options
$('#rb_Statusyes').attr('checked', true);
$('#rb_Statusno').attr('disabled', true);

//enable  options
$('#rb_Statusno').removeAttr('disabled');
```